# after withColumn by UDF, run count() gives TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I used withColumn with UDF to get a new column, then selected two columns and assigned it to a new df. But when I run count() on this new df, it gives me TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. show() works fine. I am trying to get the length of the new df.
Here is my code:

```
# Find all entities with names that are palindromes 
# (name reads the same way forward and reverse, e.g. madam):
# print the count and show() the resulting Spark DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

def is_palindrome(entity_name):
    return entity_name == entity_name[::-1]
spark_udf = udf(is_palindrome, BooleanType())
palindrome_df = cb_sdf.withColumn('is_palindrome', spark_udf('name'))
palindrome_df = palindrome_df.where(palindrome_df['is_palindrome']).select('name', 'is_palindrome')
print(palindrome_df.show())
print(palindrome_df.count())
```

Here is the output and error message I got:

```
+------+-------------+
|  name|is_palindrome|
+------+-------------+
| KAYAK|         true|
| ooVoo|         true|
| 63336|         true|
| TipiT|         true|
| beweb|         true|
|   CSC|         true|
|   CBC|         true|
|   OQO|         true|
|   SAS|         true|
|   e4e|         true|
|   PHP|         true|
|   ivi|         true|
|  ADDA|         true|
|izeezi|         true|
| siXis|         true|
| STATS|         true|
|   8x8|         true|
|   IXI|         true|
|   GLG|         true|
|   2e2|         true|
+------+-------------+
only showing top 20 rows

None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PythonException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-7fd424328e85> in <module>()
     10 palindrome_df = palindrome_df.where(palindrome_df['is_palindrome']).select('name', 'is_palindrome')
     11 print(palindrome_df.show())
---> 12 print(palindrome_df.count())

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    116                 # JVM exception message.
--> 117                 raise converted from None
    118             else:
    119                 raise

PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 604, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 596, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 211, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 132, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 200, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in mapper
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in <genexpr>
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-24-7fd424328e85>", line 7, in is_palindrome
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have nulls somewhere in your dataframe, but not in the first 20 rows that you showed. That's why you got an error when counting the whole dataframe, but not when showing 20 rows from the dataframe.

To prevent nulls from crashing the program, change your udf to:

```
def is_palindrome(entity_name):
    if entity_name is None:
        return None
    else:
        return entity_name == entity_name[::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you! I added if not entity_name: return. Then it works!